# Homology of pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This shows up as problem 2.2.26 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.

Given a pair $(X,A)$ let $X\cup CA$ be $X$ with a cone $CA$ attached at $A$. Suppose that $A$ contractible in $X$. I want to show $H_n(X,A)\cong \tilde{H}_n(X)\oplus \tilde{H}_{n-1}(A)$.

What I know: If $A$ contractible in $X$ then $X$ is a retract of $X\cup CA$ (this is part (a) of the problem) but I'm not sure what this means in terms of homology.

Also, I've proved before that $\tilde{H}_n(A)\cong \tilde{H}_{n+1}(SA)$ where $SA$ is the suspension of $A$. Combined with the observation that $(X\cup CA)/X=SA$ we get $$\tilde{H}_{n-1}(A)\cong\tilde{H}_n(SA)\cong\tilde{H}_n((X\cup CA)/X)\cong\tilde{H}_n(X\cup CA,X)$$(I believe the last equality should hold).

The direct sums leads me to think I need to use Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I haven't been able to set it up correctly.

Also, a question: since $A$ is contractible in $X$ does this mean that $H_n(X,A)=H_n(X,\{*\})=\tilde{H}_n(X)$? In that case, it would have to be that $\tilde{H}_{n-1}(A)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: No. $S^1$ is contractible in the disc, but in this case $D^2 \cup CS^1$ is $S^2$, which is not contractible. There is a relative homology long exact sequence you may want to try, with the pair $(X \cup CA,X)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller how would I get $H_n(X,A)$ from that long exact sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the long exact sequence of the pair $(X \cup CA, X)$. This is

$$\cdots \to H_{n+1}((X \cup CA)/X)) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X \cup CA) \to H_n((X \cup CA)/X) \to H_{n-1}(X) \to \cdots$$

As there is a retraction $r : X \cup CA \to X$, the homology level map $H_n(r) : H_n(X \cup CA) \to H_n(X)$ gives a retraction of the long exact sequence, breaking it into split short exact pieces

$$0 \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X \cup CA) \to H_n((X \cup CA)/X) \to 0$$

As $(X \cup CA)/X \simeq SA$ and $H_n(X \cup CA) \cong H_n(X, A)$ by excision, we have

$$H_n(X, A) \cong H_n(X) \oplus H_n(SA) \cong H_n(X) \oplus H_{n-1}(A)$$

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Since $A$ is contractible in $X$, there is a homotopy $F :A \times [0, 1] \to X$ starting with the inclusion and ending with the constant map. Define $r : X \cup CA \to X$ as $r(x) = x$ and $r([a, t]) = F(a, t)$, where $CA$ is realized as $A \times [0, 1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ pinches the top of $A \times [0, 1]$ to a single point. You can easily verify that this is continuous and well-defined.

Comment: Could you explain why the retraction breaks the long exact sequence into the short exact sequence?

Comment: @dopps $H_n(r)$ forms a right-inverse for the map $H_n(X) \to H_n(X \cup CA)$ in the long exact sequence, making $H_n(X) \to H_n(X \cup CA)$ injective for every $n$. This breaks the LES into short exact pieces, and in fact those short exact pieces are split exact by splitting lemma. This is explained at the end of chapter 2.2. in Hatcher, I believe.

Comment: Great, I think i I understand now. I suppose it wasn't necessary to use Mayer-Vietoris sequence explicitly and that's where I went wrong. Thanks for your help.